# Excel pivot table with many columns header in rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have excel data on the following format

```
Task     Team1  Team2   Team3   Team4 Team5
TaskA       X
TaskA       X    X               X
TaskC                    X               X
taskB       X    X       X       X       X
taskA       X            X
taskB       X
```

I want to have a pivot table in this format (for each Team, count of Tasks of each type)

```
         TaskA       taskB         taskC  
Team1       3           2            0
Team2       1           1            0
Team3       1           1            1
Team4       1           1            0
Team5       0           1            1
```

Any help how I can do that ? (with pivot table or anything else).

Thanks,

Comment: 1st unpivot the data using the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal . 2nd from the result of the unpivot, pivot the data as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I can't embed images, but here is a solution I found. You can use a pivot table.

Select your data source and enter the following pivot table criteria.

- Filters: (none)
- Columns: "Task"
- Rows: "Sum of Values"
- Sum of Values: "Count of Team1", "CountofTeam2", etc

[Pivot Table Criteria][1]

[image: Source Data,Pivot Table,Pivot Table Criteria]